# Missing Thumbnails for .swf files in Nautilus?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, thumbnails, swf

Before I upgraded to Maverick, .swf files used to have a thumbnail in Nautilus.
However, Nautilus doesn't generate thumbnails for them anymore, even after removing `~/.thumbnails/`, which most likely indicates that a package is missing.

How do I get Nautilus to generate thumbnails for .swf files?

EDIT: I've added a bounty, as I believe this question might still be answered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way of getting this done explained [in the Floorplanner Tech Blog](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2010/11/02/server-side-rendering-of-swf-images-using-gnash/). To compile dump-gnash on a fresh Maverick you'll need

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev libagg-dev libsdl1.2-dev libcairo-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libatk1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgif-dev libjpeg-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libspeex-dev libcurl-dev
```

And then you just follow the steps. **This will take a long time.**
**NOTE**: For Step 7 use the following script instead:

```
if [[ $3 ]]; then
    raw="$(mktemp)"
    dump-gnash $2 -P "FlashVars=url=file://$1" -D "$raw" --max-advances 1 -j 500 -k 500
    tail -c 1MB "$raw" | convert -size 500x500 -depth 8 rgba:- -separate -swap 0,2 -combine -trim png:"$3"
    trap "rm $raw" EXIT
else
    echo "Insufficient arguments (expected 3 arguments)"
    exit 1
fi
```

Once you have the final script running you just hook it into gconf-editor

```
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@swf" -t string "/usr/bin/swfthumbnailer.sh %s %i %o"
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@swf/enable" -t boolean 'true'
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-swf" -t string "/usr/bin/swfthumbnailer.sh %s %i %o"
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-swf/enable" -t boolean 'true'
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-shockwave-flash/command" -t string "/usr/bin/swfthumbnailer.sh %s %i %o"
gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-shockwave-flash/enable" -t boolean 'true'
```

Then restart (or restart gnome-settings-daemon), and you've got swf thumbs!

P.S.: This is a huge hack. A better way to do this would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: Your commands don't work: `Error while parsing options: Unknown option -i`

Comment: The bounty ends tomorrow, so if you still want to score......

Comment: After a few Adjustments, the code works. I've documented the adjustments here: http://codepad.org/ZBaYE6he ***HOWEVER***, the script will run the flashfile for a moment, which results in random background noises... I've found that a little odd, but not tragic. I just wonder if that could be done in a better way...

Comment: @nebukadnezzar I have edited the answer to include your modifications.

Answer (score 5):

The thumbnails were made with `libswfdec` (i.e. `/usr/bin/swfdec-thumbnailer` from the package `swfdec-gnome`), which was removed in Ubuntu 10.10 ("maverick").  The libswfdec author stopped development because there are already 2 other open source projects working on implementing an SWF player: gnash (which is included in Ubuntu) & lightspark (which is new and not included yet).  I am not sure if there exists a thumbnailer that uses gnash...

Comment: I don't understand why this answer gets voted up? You only explain **why** swfdec doesn't exist as such in Lucid anymore, but you don't explain how to get the thumbnails back in Lucid.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've been able to find is perhaps using [ffmmpegthumbnailer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmmpegthumbnailer) to create thumbnails for you and that should handle the `.swf` files.

This [blog post](http://tuxcanfly.appspot.com/2010/05/ffmpegthumbnailer-vs-totem-video-thumbnailer) has the instructions.

Comment: ffmpegthumbnailer appears to be incompatible with compressed SWF files, which is defacto the default filetype for .swf files: `[swf @ 0x8348e40]Compressed SWF format not supported` (after running `ffmpegthumbnailer -f -s 128 -i test.swf  -o out.png`)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer should simply be to install swfdec-gnome, but the Lucid version. Not hard to do, just go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/da/lucid/swfdec-gnome and select your architecture. Then just do what you did previously to make it work; it seems to just randomly kick in for me, as I recall. Maybe after a log out/restart. Good luck to you.