# Thumbnail preview of flash files? (swf)

Tags: 11.04, gnome, flash, previews

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing Thumbnails for .swf files in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16867/missing-thumbnails-for-swf-files-in-nautilus)

I have Gnome and Ubuntu 11.04.

As I've got a lot of flash files, I would to have a preview for them.

Is it possible also to have the previews for a specific directory?

I've tried also installing ffmpegthumbnailer package but it still doesn't work

```
ffmpegthumbnailer -i file.swf -o file.png 
[swf @ 0x934ab0]max_analyze_duration reached
[swf @ 0x934ab0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Seeking in video failed, will use first frame
[swf @ 0x934b10]max_analyze_duration reached
[swf @ 0x934b10]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

What can I try?

Comment: The question above is for ubuntu 10.10 ... Not work on 11.04 :(